# MVC ASP.NET CORE, Uploading files sometime the file being uploaded become corrupted / size 0 byte

Tags: c#, upload, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am trying to upload files in my mvc core and it works, however, sometime the file being uploaded is like corrupted or size 0 bytes. Does anyone ever experienced something like this?
The initial file size being uploaded is not large at all.

Thanks.

```
public IActionResult UploadCertificateFile(IFormFile UploadCertificate)
        {
            var parsedContentDisposition =
                   ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(UploadCertificate.ContentDisposition);
            var filename = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
                "Uploads", parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
            {
                UploadCertificate.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: show code maybe? How am I supposed to know whats wrong?

Comment: @kriss Noted. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, you using CopyToAsync and not calling await there, I think you should make async Task<IActionResult> and call await in UploadCertificate.CopyToAsync line, or just use CopyTo (but is better for I/O to make it async)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is using CopyToAsync and not calling await, I think you should make your method declaration async Task and call await in UploadCertificate.CopyToAsync line, or just use CopyTo (but is better for I/O to make it async)

File might not be copied fully, when you thread is killed, so this is why your file is corrupted.